# Accessing Related Model inside the mutator

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have question about my problem, so let me explain..

I have these Model which is **Product** and **ProductVariant** , the ProductVariant has "belongsTo" relation into the Product model.. and Product model have "hasMany" relation into the **ProductVariant**

My Question is...

i did createMany for variation from the product which is like

```
Product->variant()->create($variantProducts);
```

and i'd like to create some mutator on the ProductVariant model to manipulate one column called "sku".

my problem is, how to get some column value from the mutator to get data from the related model ( Product ) , in this case i want to get the category_id of the Product from the ProductVariant mutator

i try to do this , but it seems doesnt work

```
public function setSkuAttribut($v){
    // product() is belongsTo relation to the product model
    $cat = $this->product()->category_id;
    dd($cat);
}
```

but it returns me this error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$category_id
```

Any helps would be really appreciated.. thankyou :)

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove the brackets? `$cat = $this->product->category_id`

Comment: still got error, now the error is Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It may be silly but are you sure that `$this` has a product attached to it? If you `dd($this->product)` do you get an object?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `product()` relation method as a method, which means you're receiving a Builder instance. In order to get the model instance, you'll either have to execute `->product()->get()->category_id`, which will make a new query on each occasion or use the lazy eager loading with `->product->category_id` which will use an already loaded relation instance if present.