# laravel access related model using mutator during $user->posts()->create([...])

Tags: laravel

I have User and Post models.
Would like to access the User when the mutator for the post's title is being called at the time of the post creation. Similar to a [question from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537775/accessing-related-model-inside-the-mutator).

But I am unable to access the User inside the Posts title mutator.
Tried `$this->user->id` (preferred). Also tried: `$this->user_id`, `$this->user()->get()->id`.

```
>>> User::first()->posts()->create(['title'=>'test '.now()])

PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "id" on null  <<<=== when trying $this->user->id
=> App\Models\Post {#4155
     title: "test 2021-05-08 11:41:55", <<<=== title is shown before user_id
     user_id: 1,                        <<<=== but in migration user_id is defined *before* title
     updated_at: "2021-05-08 11:41:55",
     created_at: "2021-05-08 11:41:55",
     id: 1,
     user: null, <<<=== note "user" attribute is added as result of the $this->user->id
   }
```

Would think the user is definitely known at that time, as we're using that user to add a post to.

If I make the `user_id` fillable, then this one works as expected (for that one: the array order matters):

```
Post::create(['user_id'=>User::first()->id, 'title'=>'test '.now()])
```

But, that's less... eloquent.

My config + test details:

```
// Post.model

    protected $fillable = [
        // 'user_id', // also tried with making user_id fillable
        'title',
    ];

    public function setTitleAttribute($value) {
        // dump($this->user_id); // null
        // dump($this->user); // null (& adds empty user property to this)
        // dump($this->user->id); // PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "id" on null (& adds property)
        // dump($this->user()->get()); // empty collection Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
        // dump($this->user()->toSql()); // select * from "users" where "users"."id" is null

        $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

```
// User.model

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

```
// posts migration

        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Using mysql as DB.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the safest + cleanest: use [boot event closure 'creating'](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events), which is triggered after the mutators and right before data is saved to the database.

```
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function (Post $post) {
            // now we have both $post->user and $post->title
            dump($post->user->name);
            dump($post->title);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

can you provide more detail?

try this

```
auth()->user()->id
```

if user is logged in

if u want select user from db

```
User::where("filed name","value")->first()->id
```

Comment: Used tinker. User::first()->id gives 1.